# Selenium exits fullscreen when clicking at a link

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

The Selenium web driver exists fullscreen whenever clicking at a link or opening a new URL.
Any remedies to force fullscreen?

*I am using the fullscreen_window() method.

Google Chrome 91 /
Linux KDE Neon

Comment: Did not understand your question, when you click on a link, it opens a browser, and you you want to maximize the screen size ?

Comment: @cruisepandey It is working properly at the initialization, it opens the requested URL with fullscreen mode, but the second I try to click at any link provided by the webpage, it exists fullscreen.

Comment: When you typed "exists", did you actually mean "exits"? Totally different meaning.

Comment: @ConradAlbrecht I apologize for the typo mate, what I meant is exits.

Comment: Please, read through [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in order to provide enough information for someone to help you.

Comment: @Kepler186 : Okay I thought the same, can you run the below code and let me know if that works ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say when you click on a link like this :

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('some xpath').click()
```

and a new tab opens up :

and then you switch it like this  :

```
driver.switch_to.window(hadles[1])
```

it would not open screen in full size, you would need to again do this  :

```
driver.maximize_window()
```

Comment: The thing is, I want to make it fullscreen, as in F11, to hide the tabs and also menu bar, the maximize_window method only fits the window to the screen. Is there an alternative way to fullscreen other than fullscreen_window()?

Comment: I think I should denote that I am using the cursor to perform clicks and open links!

Comment: I think there is. let me try with chrome options or we can try to press F11 also

Comment: That's actually brilliant. I tried with Pynput module and I simulated an F11 press and it worked, and neither clicking a link un-fullscreen-ed it lol ... thank you so much friend!